# How to pronounce "they're" in everyday spoken english (very fast contraction)?

Tags: pronunciation

there are lots of Pronounce Contractions in American English Pronunciation.

It sounds like the tutorial is saying (a video link with a time stamp)

> I'm going to do that
>   with all of my portions.
>   **once they're** all portioned out

where **once they're** sounds like "onther", did I listen it correctly? Should I pronounce the say way?

Comment: No, pronounce it correctly. You can use contractions with more confidence when you become fluent. Note that "they're" is itself already a contraction.

Comment: When I hear people say "they're" it nomally comes out as there